# Android - Get reference to TabActivity from tabbed content

Tags: android, android-activity, tabactivity

I have a class for my `TabActivity`

```
public class DashboardActivity extends TabActivity
```

This has several tabs and an actionbar.  One of these tabs is a list of items.

```
public class WalletActivity extends ExpandableListActivity
```

I want to be able to run an asynchronous task in one of the child activities, and while it is running have the spinner show in my actionbar.  I already do this within an `AsyncTask` in my tab activity

```
ActionBar actionBar = (ActionBar)findViewById(R.id.actionbar);

if(actionBar != null)
    actionBar.setProgressBarVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

How can I reference the `DashboardActivity` that is hosting my tabbed `WalletActivity`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a small method that recieves an Activity and returns the current context. If the Activity has a parent (the TabActivity, an ActivityGroup, etc), it returns that context in order to show the spinner/dialog/whatever in there.

```
public Context getDialogContext(Activity act) {
    Context context;
    if (act.getParent() != null) 
        context = act.getParent();
    else context = act;
        return context;
}
```

Comment: That works great.  I modified it slightly to return a generic type so I can get the actual class type of the parent instead of a `Context`, and null if it isn't found.